# Issue Inheriting Form properties and methods

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to build a Base custom form and then have my applications inherit the properties and methods that are within the base form.   I do believe that I have setup the forms correctly, but every time I open the new form that has inherited the base form with VS 2010, VS crashes and I have to restart the IDE.  Here is the code on the two forms;

Base custom form;

```
namespace TGBSoftware
{
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public int gnTaxYear { get; set; }
    public string gsTableName { get; set; }
    public string gsUserId { get; set; }

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Form that inherits the base form;

```
namespace TGBSoftware.CompuTax.Forms
{
public partial class RealEstate : BaseForm
{
    public RealEstate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when VS crashes? If so, list them.

Comment: The base form contains visual components ?

Comment: What is the content of the InitializeComponent() in the base form?

Comment: I have not been able to find any error logs that VS is creating. The base form has nothing besides the properties above.  I have not even added any methods yet.  Here are the contents of InitializeComponent      private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // BaseForm
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(785, 407);
            this.Name = "BaseForm";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.BaseForm_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help, but the crazy solution was to delete the project and start a new one.  Starting in SafeMode and with logging really did not provide any insight.

jrb - I tried doing both, with and without the InitializeComponent(), neither helped.  In the new project, both forms have this setting and it works fine.  I will see what happens when I create a form with navigation buttons and stuff.

Thanks again.  Have a great week.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call `InitializeComponent();`

in both forms. Try only in top form or using `base.InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Thanks jrb, I tried commenting out InitializeComponent(); in the Base Form and it crashed again.  I added base.InitializeComponent(); to the top form, with the base form still commented out, VS still crashed.

Comment: Have a look here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/winforms/thread/0a1f73b4-d9e6-4a10-9592-342f4de5a282

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is run visual studio with logging enabled:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Then look at the stack trace of the error. Most likely there is a dll reference missing, or there is a piece of code in one of the forms that needs to be surrounded with: if (!DesignMode)...

Comment: Thanks, but the activity log does not give any useful information.  It has all the modules loading until the IDE is set, then I open my Solution, open the Form and it crashes.  There is nothing in the activity log that indicates why it crashed.

Comment: Another option is to start Visual Studio in safe mode: devenv /SafeMode. This will help if there is a third party extension affecting the form designer.

Answer (score 0):

You say that "I do believe that I have setup the forms correctly".

why you don't just reinstall it again??